# Cannot understand the addressing type

Tags: linux, assembly, linux-kernel

- i am going through the assembly language code in Linux kernel.
- I found the instruction `pushl_cfi (%esp)(OFFSET)`,assuming OFFSET value to 10.
- so actually their is no operator between %esp and OFFSET values in the above instruction so i am not getting it actually how this instruction is going to execute so please help me to understand

Comment: `pushl_cfi` isn't an instruction, it's a macro.

Comment: @Michael oh i am unaware about it thanks and what about esp and offset